# Traversing a grid of pixels inside projection plane

Tags: graphics, pixel, projection

Suppose, I have a projection plane of length 2 like the below image:

[image]

If I divide the projection plane into a two dimensional
grid of screen_width x screen_height (720*480), then each pixel will be (2/720) distance apart in the x axis and (2/480) distance apart in the y axis and If I add x+(2/720) with my current co-ordinate, keeping the y constant I will move 1 pixel to the right side. Am I right?

Comment: Plus or minus round off.  Beware that stepping pixels via fractions will cause round off error to increase over time (with floating point numbers).  Make sure to calculate your position via the projection each time, not by adding the same value over and over to step through.

Comment: If I want to convert a vertex co-ordinate (x,y) to pixel co-ordinate in this case, what will i need to do? @Michael Dorgan